# view is hiding tabbarcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, tabbarcontroller

I have developed a tab based iphone application.
In this, I am facing a problem as described below:

The view associated with 1st tab bar contains 2-3 buttons. Action of these buttons are to load another view. Now on pressing these buttons the views are loading but in full size(320x480) and hiding the tab bar.
I want to load that view just above the tab bar so that tab bar is accessible.
I explicitly set the view frame in that view's viewDidLoad function, but it is not working.

Please help me out.

Comment: ya presenting the view with this code: Cities *cv=[[Cities alloc] initWithNibName:@"Cities" bundle:nil];
 cv.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
 [self presentModalViewController:cv animated:YES]; 
 [cv release];

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't/can't push the view controller onto the navigation stack?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

You need to start with view based application. And then create a **UITabbarController** in you appDelegate file.

Appdelegate.h

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController;
// set properties

Appdelegate.m

// Synthsize

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate=self;

//Adding Search,Nearby,Map,AboutUs,Favorites Tabs to tabBarController  
Search * search = [[Search alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *searchNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:search];  

Nearby* nearby = [[Nearby alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *nearbyNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nearby];  

Map* map = [[Map alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *mapNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:map];  

AboutUs* aboutUs = [[AboutUs alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *aboutUsNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aboutUs];  

Favorites* favorites = [[Favorites alloc] init];  
UINavigationController *favoritesNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favorites];  

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchNav,nearbyNav,mapNav,aboutUsNav,favoritesNav, nil];  
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;  

[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

You can accordingly manage in which tab you want to place navigation controller or only a view controller.

Then in each of the view controllers mentioned above you need to implement

```
- (id)init {}
```

in which you can set Tab name and image.
Rename the tbs as per your requirement. Place 2 buttons in the one of the views which is Navigation controller.
Hope this helps.

Comment: But here Every thing I have done through IB….Now according to my requirement there will be a button on the view with respective to 1st tab bar and on pressing that button another view will load….now problem is that this loaded view is loaded in in whole screen so that tabbarcontroller is hiding….

Comment: I always prefer using code rather than IB. Just check that you are correctly adding views in navigation bar and tabbar controller.there may somewhere you are miissing to add second view i.e the view which appears when button is clicked, in tabbar.

Answer (score 1):

Typical application navigation allows the user to freely move forwards and backwards, between tabs etc.  This is facilitated by pushing and popping ViewController's on the navigation bar stack.

In certain scenarios you want to force the user to complete some task and this is when you should use a modal view controller.  When the application presents a modal view the idea is that the user should NOT be able to navigate away from the view, instead they should only be able to complete or cancel the action and hence the default behavior for a modal view is to hide the navigation bar, tab bar etc.

It sounds to me from your description that you are performing navigation and not a modal task and thus can I recommend using pushViewController instead of presentModalViewController?

If you are only using presentModalViewController because you want a bottom to top animation then you'll need to use a custom animation.